# Cannot find "My Apps" option in iTunes Connect, to upload my app on the app-store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I am new to iOS app distribution (have developed apps but haven't uploaded any), and now i want to upload an app on app-store. I wasn't enrolled in apple developer program at first but then i joined a Team/Company which had been enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, and in that Team, i was granted the role of Admin, because without that i couldn't create App-ID for my App as u can see in this image [image] ... But now that i have created the App-ID, and also the development and distribution certificate and am ready to upload app onto App-store, **I cannot find the "MY APPS" option in the itunesconnect.apple.com**... On its home-page, there are options of Apps, Artists, Books, Media... as shown in this second image..[image] but when i click on the Apps option i am taken this link **www.apple.com/itunes/working-itunes/sell-content/apps/** where i am being shown a button of **Get Started** and when i click it it takes me back to **developer.apple.com/programs/** prompting me to enroll in a developer program. Why am I getting this? I am already working with a team that is enrolled in this program, an i have been assigned the Role of an Admin, so why can't I find the option to upload the App?

Is there a possibility that i am only granted Admin Access for developer program in **developer.apple.com** but not for **iTunes Connect** and is there a difference in that???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: This is off-topic: but since you are new try this URL.    https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/    if it doesn't work that is not a paid apple account.

Comment: Does the question need to be about programming to be asked? I have put proper tags.. and have edited (and got edit by other person) the question

Comment: @RJE yes i have gone to this link many times, but it always shows me a message **you have been signed out. Sign in to iTunes Connect** even though i am already signed in... so thats why i am asking, that, does my role in developer.apple.com (from the first image) differ from my role in iTunes Connect

Comment: If it ask for log-in just enter your credentials and login. If it doesn't point you to developer dashboard your account is not a valid paid account.

Comment: @RJE yes when i login i still does not point me to developer dashboard.. But the Team for which i am working for has a valid paid account, otherwise i would not be able to create iOS developer and distribution certificates and also the App-ID for my app... [https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) by checking this link i think these are 2 different thing, i.e. the role in developer program and the role in iTunes Connect

Comment: i think this version is not have the same name of your previous version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

There are two different roles in development center and iTunes connect.

Comment: okay so these are 2 different things.. :) thanks for the help :) actually the team i am working for has granted me admin access for development center, and now they want me to upload app but i seems like they havent granted me access over iTunes Connect

Answer (score 1):

This same thing happened to me, try deleting the cookies in your web browser.

At that point I was asked to log in again, at which point I was able to see the interface.

Click the 'lock' button in browser: 
[image]

The click remove
[image]

Then you'll hopefully see this!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when my I reset my password. Open a private browser window. In chrome, ctrl + shift + n to open incognito tab. Log in and if you have access you should now see the correct menu.